# More efficient way to compare records in DataGridView

Tags: vb.net

I have a DataGridView (bound to a DataTable) which has data something like this:

```
| Col1 | Col2 |
|------|------|
| 1    | Y    |
| 1    | N    |
| 2    | Y    |
```

What I need to do is find where a duplicated value in `Col1` has a different value in `Col2`.

At the moment I do a nested `For Each` loop to compare each row in the DataGridView with every row in the DataGridView but this is, obviously, very slow and scales horribly... Cost is somewhere around n^n.

Is there a better way I can do this without having to loop over the whole DataGridview for every record?

I want to filter the DataGridView to only show records where there is a mismatch between records of value in Col1 and values in Col2 (in this case, '1' should be shown because it contains both 'Y' and 'N').

Comment: What is the desired output from the example table above?

Comment: To go through a Datagridview `For each` is usually the only way to search for a value etc. for all i can think off the top of my head

Comment: @Magnus Sorry, missed that bit. I've edited the question.